# first printf not executed, after entering 3 numbers both printf executed in same line

Tags: c, printf

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    float a,b,c,avg;
    printf("Enter 3 numbers");
    scanf("%f%f%f",&a,&b,&c);
    avg=(a+b+c)/3;
    printf("\nAvg is %f",avg);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}enter code here
```

in the above program after run the program first we have to enter three numbers then we get the output like
Enter 3 nymbers
Avg is....
which means after run the program nothing showning in console first printf is not executing why?

Comment: Try it in a regular terminal instead of the Eclipse console.

Comment: Also try putting newlines at the ends of your printfs. This may be because of line buffering.

Comment: Flush `stdout` after `printf()` without newline at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The ouput to `stdout` is line buffered by default. This means that anything sent to `stdout` only gets transferred to your screen if either you output a newline or the internal buffer is full.

In this case you do not output a newline in your first `printf`, so nothing shows on-screen. If you do not want a newline call `fflush(stdout)` to force the output.

Some (online) systems may be configured to not buffer, so there the experience can be different.